# Why do we believe in a "force" driven universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, newtonian-mechanics, string-theory, quantum-information

Why do we not believe in the potential for a "unified force field" universe, to the exclusion of the belief in the potential for a mechanical, gear driven universe, if the correct shape for the gear were found?

And why cannot the correct shape for that gear be this shape:

[image]

And in light of the things we DON'T KNOW, is it "wild speculation" to consider such mechanical, gear driven, aether filed universe such as those envisioned by both Newton and Einstein (for five years prior to relativity), may actually exist??

Things we "don't know":

- the true nature of the inside of every atom
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xLuZNKhlY
- the true nature of the Higg's Bosun
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=649iUqrOKuE
  Please make note of the answer to the question, “does this mean we have found the Standard Model Higg’s Bosun??” @ 5:40 in the video.
- the true nature of "space" itself
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jHsq36_NTU

So if it IS "wild speculation" to consider a mechanical "filling" for the universe, at levels of detail below our ability to "see" it, "WHY" is is "wild speculation??  and "WHY" do we only seek a "unified force field", and not a unified Mechanical Motion Field??

REFERENCES ADDED to Newtonian and Einsteinian thinking:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork_universe
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories
http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_current_status_of_Einstein-Aether_theory_of_gravity
http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7689
http://fqxi.org/community/articles/display/129
http://www.academia.edu/355491/Reviving_Gravitys_Aether_In_Einsteins_Universe

REFERENCE TO CONTEMPORARY WORK, 
http://phys.org/news170586562.html
http://www.quantamagazine.org/20140416-times-arrow-traced-to-quantum-source/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(arrow_of_time)
http://preposterousuniverse.com/research/    (Sean Carroll)

Comment: i would say (and this is not mainstream view), that this is just a "prevalent" or "politicaly-correct" way of thinking in physics currently (of course i'm using analogies here )

Comment: ok, i read the whole question, my previous comment holds, but relating to "gear", "ether" driven universe, i dont understand anything, is there any description/definition pf these concepts (that can derive the same results that are known to hold for experiments) or is this just techno-bubble??

Comment: I understand it is not "popular" to think the universe may be "simpler" and "more intuitive" than the models of it we have constructed (relativity, bent time, super string, wave-particle duality, quantum theory, the four fundamental forces, et al.).  But with all the mysteries, and unknowns, I wish I could figure out "why" we are so heavily "meantally invested" in believing we are on the correct path, as to exclude others, or relegate them to wild speculation??  What MAKES the fundamental forces NOT be "Wild Speculation"??  "WHY"???

Comment: hmm, ok this can easily be turned into a chat (or flame war), but i will give a couple of answers.The concepts used to define physical properties (and theorise about the cosmos) are a result of previous notions (that wre found to work) plus (dont underestimate this) politics.So these are the 2 things that make the current discourse. Of course there are alternative formulations that are equivalent (the criterion is experiments and correct results). i think i understand the motive of the question and tried to give an account (personaly i disagree with much of current physics discourse)

Comment: @AlistairRiddoch: we're not invested in these paradigms, so much as they work, and they explain a ton of unexpected things.  In each instance, they're actually simpler than what came before, as you can really easily see formulating electrodynamics with and without special relativity, for instance.

Comment: Clockwork Universe was an analogy used to theorise about the cosmos which used classical notions of the time (and citcumstances) to do the theorising. This is not adequate after recent results. Aether theories are generaly considered superfluous (not wrong), but there are viable approaches to ether theory. The rest links either i did not read or have read already

Comment: If physics were related to the A B C's, (Already Been Concluded), and D equal's Dark Matter, we balk at the idea of discussing F for Final.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer  Thank you Jerry, for the heads up.  Do you have any idea where theoretical physics can be discussed logically and openly, without contention and trolling??  New thoughts.  Outside (or INSIDE) the box, depending on who you ask??

Comment: @AlistairRiddoch: That would be here, but it would require that one can tell the difference between theoretical physics and nonsense, which, I admit, is hard enough even in the gap between real theoretical physics and real mathematical physics.

Answer (score 4):

If you have another model, then use it to generate a set of predictions, and let's compare those to the predictions we get in the world we see.

If you think there's some ether filling the universe, then write down some properties it has, and make some predictions with those properties.  Talking in vague generalities will only lead you down a rabbit hole of nonsense.

Any professional physicist would tell you that our existing physics leaves a lot that we don't know, but at the same time, that it predicts more from fewer assumptions than any other system ever has.  If you can beat that, then go ahead.  You should start with high-ish precision stuff like the properties of the hydrogen atom and the Lamb shift if you're starting over from scratch.